# How to fix Null check operator used on a null value in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am trying to save data to firebase, I used if(_formKey.currentState!.validate()) to valid the Textfield, and I get an error "Null check operator used on a null value in Flutter", Can anyone help me, please?
You can check the code.

Comment: `_formKey.currentState` is null is what it says, can you verify that?

Comment: hello @PhaniPavan I solved the problem by changing this function  onPressed: saveQuizData(quizId), to onPressed { saveQuizData(quizId); }. that's it.